# How to get first and last row of each island?

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

So I recently got excellent help on a problem. However, I need to get a little more precise, which hopefully is doable in SQL.

This was my last problem:

- [Select only rows that has a column changed from the rows before it, given an unique ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62214728/select-only-rows-that-has-a-column-changed-from-the-rows-before-it-given-an-uni)

Clarificiation:

The help I got in that problem was to give me the start of every Island. However, I want the start and stop of every Island instead.

My nuance is this:

```
personID | status | unixtime | column d | column e | column f
    1        2       213214      x            y        z
    1        2       213325      x            y        z
    1        2       213326      x            y        z
    1        2       213327      x            y        z
    1        2       213328      x            y        z <-- I want this
    1        3       214330      x            y        z <-- Any of this is OK     
    1        3       214331      x            y        z
    1        3       214332      x            y        z <-- I want this or
    1        2       324543      x            y        z <-- I want this
```

So instead of the start of the islands, I want the end of the island. If I get something in between it's totally ok, preferably it would be the end. But I really want what is the "right before" and "right after" the status changes, if this gives any meaning. This could be a specific status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query produces all rows that either end or start a partition (or both in case of a single-row partition):

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , lag(status)  OVER w IS DISTINCT FROM status AS partition_start
        , lead(status) OVER w IS DISTINCT FROM status AS partition_end
   FROM   tbl
   WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY personID ORDER BY unixtime)
   ) sub
WHERE (partition_start OR partition_end)
ORDER  BY personID, unixtime;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4094204697b3ca0a0b2e783d82bb66cd)*

Note that with `PARTITION BY personID`, rows with a different `personID` do not interrupt the "island". I added rows to your test case in the fiddle to demonstrate the effect.

If your requirements are different, you'll have to define how.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
       case when status <> lag(status,1,NULL) over(partition by personID order by unixtime) 
            then 1
            when lag(status,1,NULL) over(partition by personID order by unixtime) is null
            then 1
            else 0 end as start_status,
       case when status <> lead(status,1,NULL) over(partition by personID order by unixtime) 
            then 1
            when lead(status,1,NULL) over(partition by personID order by unixtime) is null
            then 1
            else 0 end as end_status
      from mytable t
) t
where end_status = 1
--or start_status = 1    -- uncomment this line if you want start statuses as well
```